# flutter - Error: A value of type 'PermissionStatus' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'bool'

Tags: android, flutter, hybrid-mobile-app

I got below error after recently flutter update (I'm not updating code for 3 months but the last build was successful).

> lib/src/blocs/home/home_bloc.dart:141:23: **Error: A value of type 'PermissionStatus' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'bool'.**
>
> - 'PermissionStatus' is from 'package:location/location.dart' ('../programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location-2.5.4/lib/location.dart').
>
>   _permission = await _locationService.requestPermission();

any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

https://pub.dev/packages/location_permissions

```
import 'package:location_permissions/location_permissions.dart';
PermissionStatus permissionStatus = await LocationPermissions().requestPermissions();

PermissionStatus permission = await LocationPermissions().checkPermissionStatus();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
PermissionStatus permission  =  await location.hasPermission();


    if(permission==PermissionStatus.GRANTED){
      return location.getLocation();
    }else{
      location.requestPermission();
    }
```

Comment: i face error "Error: Getter not found: 'GRANTED'." any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (result == PermissionStatus.GRANTED) {
    location.onLocationChanged().listen((locationData) {
      if (locationData != null) {
        _locationController.add(UserLocation(
          latitude: locationData.latitude,
          longitude: locationData.longitude,
        ));
      }
    });
  }
```